# How do I run a shell script prior to launch.json in vs code for cucumber-js

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio-code, cucumberjs, vscode-tasks

So I have a shell script that holds environment variables env.sh:

```
echo "Running Environment Variables Script"
#########################################################
# Run-time Options
# set to 'dev', 'qa', or 'stg'
export NODE_ENV='qa'
# Running Mode
export HEADLESS='truef'
# Set Debug mode 'true' or 'false'`enter code here`
export EPAY_GUI_AUTOMATION_TEST_DEBUG_MODE='true'
#########################################################
# yadda
# yadda
# yadda
```

In VS Code, I also am using the following .vscode/tasks.json:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "loadEnvironmentVariables",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": ". ${workspaceFolder}/env.sh",
        "isBackground": true,
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "silent",
            "focus": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In VS Code, I also am using the following .vscode/launch.json:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "foo",
        "preLaunchTask": "loadEnvironmentVariables",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js",
        "args": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/features/01_MAT_ManualWorkflow_QBO.feature"
        ]
    },
```

I use the same shell script env.sh in my package.json.  This way, I have one set of environment variables I need to manage.

I when I run this in debug mode, the env file is run (I see "Running Environment Variables Script" in the terminal output).  But then I get a pop-up saying "The specified task can not be tracked."

I can't seem to get past this issue to be able to run the cucumber-js.

I'm running this on MAcOs.

---

UPDATE 1

---

I tried just referring to the npm script, by having the launch.json:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "mat",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "args": [ "mat" ]
    },
```

and where "mat" refers to the package.son:

```
"mat": ". ./env.sh; node ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --tags @MAT
```

but that did do jack-squat for me :(

Comment: Why not launch.json in the end of Shell script? If you launch Shell script from launch.json the I guess this Shell script will NOT set/pass Variables for current JSON session.
But Shell script will launch in a separate session which will be out of JSON scope.

Comment: I tried - see update 1

Comment: Did you ever come up with a way to do this?  I have some tasks I need to run with some environment variables set by sourcing a shell script, however I'm not seeing a way to do this, really.  I tried specifying an `inputs` item of `type` `command` however I'm not having much luck referencing it.